# Why does the default VCL produced by Magento force search requests to bypass Varnish?

Tags: magento2, search, varnish

The default VCL produced by Magento from the admin has the following few lines in it:

```
# Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
    return (pass);
}
```

Now I understand why Magento would want requests to bypass Varnish for checkout URLs, but why search requests? Is it purely because search results can change frequently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because search results change frequently and Magento doesn't know how to invalidate those results. And because the world isn't a perfect place to live :(

Anyway, you can do just:

```c
# Bypass shopping cart, checkout
if (req.url ~ "/checkout") {
    return (pass);
}
```

(note removed `catalogsearch` from condition)

And do some "microcaching" of popular search results by still having Varnish cache search results, simply with reasonable TTL. In `vcl_backend_response`:

```c
# "Microcache" for search
if (bereq.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
    set beresp.ttl = 30m;
}
```

See always up-to-date [full VCL for Magento 2](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/varnish-vcl-magento-2) which includes this.

Comment: That's a great suggestion for a micro-cache, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the biggest problems with running varnish on a Magento 1.x site was the fact that the cart page would be auto-magically cached.  So if I was the first person to add something to my cart, the next person who added something (different) to their cart would see what I added.  (Unless you specifically told varnish via the VCL to bypass the cart and checkout pages.)

Same thing can happen on a catalog search page result - the filterable navigation on the left hand side of a normal search results page can easily be cached.

Using a default Luma theme on Magento 2.1, here's a sample URL:
http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=yoga

Here's a screenshot of the results:
[image: Magento 2 - search results page]

On a page like this, you have the left navigation that can open or close, sort by (relevance, price), or the grid view vs. list view, items per page.